# if statement is not saving variable data #Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variables, return

**I GOT THE ANSWER OF M POST THANKS FOR HELPING ME AND WISH OTHERS LEARN FROM MY MISTAKES GOOD LUCK ALL**

I Have Folders that take in .meta files and want to save each filename in variable ,
all folder take in the same meta file name but I added the folder name into the file with hypthen means
-> foldername + '-' + filename

and want to print the file name in each folder into file that I created in specific  driver and used os.chdir() to load into file path

so when im going to print each folder meta file name into this file its not saving the var

```
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.') :
        print('loop')
        for file in files :
            print('file')
            if file.endswith('.meta'):
                print('meta')
                METAPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
                METABase = os.path.basename(dirpath)
                if True :
                    if file.startswith(METABase + '-' + 'handling'):
                        HandlingFile = "'" + file + "'"
                        return HandlingFile
                    elif file.startswith(METABase + '-' + 'vehicles'):
                        VehiclesFile = "'" + file + "'"
                        return VehiclesFile
                    elif file.startswith(METABase + '-' + 'carvariations'):
                        CarVariationsFile = "'" + file + "'"
                        return CarVariationsFile
                    elif file.startswith(METABase + '-' + 'carcols'):
                        CarcolsFile = "'" + file + "'"
                        return CarcolsFile
                    elif file.startswith(METABase + '-' + 'dlctext'):
                        DLCTextFile = "'" + file + "'"
                        return DLCTextFile
                    print(HandlingFile, VehiclesFile ,CarVariationsFile ,CarcolsFile ,DLCTextFile)
```

***Error :***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonEx\MyFiveMPython\test.py", line 220, in <module>
    Stress_Veh()
  File "D:\pythonEx\MyFiveMPython\test.py", line 213, in Stress_Veh
    print(HandlingFile, VehiclesFile ,CarVariationsFile ,CarcolsFile ,DLCTextFile)
NameError: name 'HandlingFile' is not defined
```

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]. The line causing the error isn't even in the code you provided: `HandlingFile = HandlingFile`

Comment: sorry its mistake from me , forgot to update the error after that I updated the code, check the new error please

Comment: If you read  that `print` that means *none of the conditions were true* so *none of those variables were defined*.

Comment: Thanks, I tested and its true that none of the conditions were true

Answer (score 0):

delete these five statements.  They're the source of your error, and they don't do anything.

```
                HandlingFile = HandlingFile
                VehiclesFile = VehiclesFile
                CarVariationsFile = CarVariationsFile
                CarcolsFile = CarcolsFile
                DLCTextFile = DLCTextFile
```

Comment: really?  You're getting an error on line 198, with the "HandlingFile == HandlingFile" that you just deleted?

Answer (score 0):

To cut down your code a bit...

```py
if file.startswith(...):
    HandlingFile = <some stuff>
    return HandlingFile

print(HandlingFile...)
```

When your "if" statement returns False, HandlingFile is never defined.

Aaah! Now I understand what those extra five statements were trying to do... you were trying to initalize your variables.  You didn't want to do

```
HandlingFile = HandlingFile
```

you wanted

```
HandlingFile = None  # or False, or '' or something else
```

Comment: but when I tried to use None or '' , it prints None or whitespaces .. But got the answer that if returns False so its not defining the vars... Thanks for help